# CSS not applied for the HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my web application, I'm trying to add a card to the view using JavaScript to a section.
This is the card I'm using to apply to mine --> https://uiverse.io/JohnnyCSilva/ugly-stingray-77

I made a few changes because when I used the CSS to my view, it mixed with current CSS styles and showed the card a different view. So I added **special** tag to that css.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("getStaffMembers", "Home")',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.Success) {
      var staffList = data.StaffList;
      var staffListDiv = $('#staffListDiv');

      for (var i = 0; i < staffList.length; i++) {
        var staffCard = $('<div>').addClass('col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-4 card special-section card');

        // Add a data attribute to store Staff ID
        staffCard.data('staff-id', staffList[i].ID);

        var imgDiv = $('<div>').addClass('img');
        var textDiv = $('<div>').addClass('textBox');
        var textContent = $('<div>').addClass('textContent');
        var staffName = $('<p>').addClass('h1').text(staffList[i].Staff_Name);

        textContent.append(staffName);
        textDiv.append(textContent);

        staffCard.append(imgDiv, textDiv);
        staffListDiv.append(staffCard);


      }
    } else {
      console.log('Error fetching staff members');
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('Error fetching staff members');
  }
});
```

```css
.special-section .card {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 290px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #353535;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.special-section .card:hover>.img {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.special-section .img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(#d7cfcf, #9198e5);
}

.special-section.card:hover>.img {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: linear-gradient(#9198e5, #712020);
}

.special-section .textBox {
  width: calc(100% - 90px);
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins' sans-serif;
}

.special-section.textContent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.special-section .span {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.special-section.h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.special-section .p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section2" class="section text-center">
  <h2 style="margin-top: 40px;">Select the Staff Member</h2>
  <div class="row justify-content-center" id="staffListDiv" style="margin-top: 200px;">
    <!-- Staff cards will be dynamically generated here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The thing is when the dynamically cards are generated into the view, the css not applied. Need to know how to fix this?

Comment: Which element of the card does not get its css correctly? the one with "col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-4 card special-section card" classes?

Comment: In your CSS, in some cases you have `.special-section .card` and in other cases `.special-section.card`.  I think you want them all to have no space, since your special-section element is also your card element (and not an ancestor of the card element like using a space suggests)